# Cannot save file when deploying to JBoss AS through maven

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I use the following method to save a picture through primefaces uploader:

```
public void carregarArquivo(FileUploadEvent event)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream();
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
    File arquivo = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator
            + "images" + File.separator + "tmp" + File.separator
            + numMatricula + ".png");
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        System.out.println("Arquivo salvo com sucesso em "
                + arquivo.getAbsolutePath());
        tmpFotoPath = "/images/tmp/" + numMatricula + ".png";
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        System.out.println("Arquivo salvo com sucesso em "
                + arquivo.getAbsolutePath());
        tmpFotoPath = "/images/tmp/" + numMatricula + ".png";
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
    }
}
```

When deploying a standard eclipse web projet to JBoss AS 7.1.1 the method works properly and it saves the image to /home/hfluz/Servers/standalone 7.1.1/standalone/deployments/IdentificacaoInstitucional.war/images/tmp/

So I created a maven webapp and implemented the same class and xhtml page (also same web.xml). JBoss AS maven plugin by default deploys my app to another folder and when it tries to create an instance of FileOutputStream with the File as argument (output = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);) I get the following error:

/home/hfluz/Servers/standalone 7.1.1/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp3081e1eb97c799e8/content-b5984e02f5b23513/images/tmp/200701500694.png (No such file or directory)

The issue happens with both windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**
I guess I found out the problem.

When I deploy a ant webapp the following structure is created:
 - identificacao_institucional.war
    - WEB-INF
    - META-INF
    - images
       - tmp
    - index.xhtml

When I deploy a maven webapp this is the structure created in the JBoss deploy folder:
 - identificacao_institucional.war
    - META-INF
    - resources
    - WEB-INF
    - index.xhtml

For some reason the maven app doesn't create the images directory and its subdirectories. I thought that maybe calling "arquivo.mkdirs()" and "arquivo.createNewFile()" before calling "new FileOutputStream(arquivo);" would solve this problem, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was actually my fault.

I was so focused on comparing the java and xhtml code between both projects that I didn't realize I forgot to create images folder in maven project.

In the case of deploy through jboss as maven plugins, the empty directories were not included, so I added dummy files (documenting folder purpose) to include them during maven deploy to tmp/vfs.

James, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

The WAR is exposed through a virtual file system. It's reading the contents of a WAR which is essentially a compressed file. The `java.io.File` has no concept of the virtual file system.

The reason it works from eclipse is it's being deployed as an exploded deployment. Meaning it's just a normal file structure that's not compressed.

You could use an exploded WAR deployment that simple serves and images, then write to that directory. There might be a better way to server static content like that too. I just haven't looked into it.

Comment: Is there any advantage in deploying the webapp through a virtual file system instead of as a exploded WAR that justifies the choice made by jboss as maven plugin? Or maybe a way to deploy to JBoss AS as an exploded war through maven?

Comment: The maven plugin uses the API which deploys the archive. There's probably a plugin that could just copy the exploded files to the directory.

Comment: Actually apparently this issue is not caused by VFS.

I deployed my maven webapp as an exploded war through JBoss Devstudio. The exactly same issue is still happening (No such file or directory).

Both projects are identical, but one is a maven webapp and the other one is a webapp created by devstudio (ant).

Comment: I updated the main post, maven webapp is not creating "images" folder when deploying to JBoss.